# Integrating CakePHP with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I'm in a bit of a dilemma here. I have hired someone to develop a workforce platform for me in CakePHP. The idea is that I want to use WordPress as my main CMS and connect that platform to the website. 
I have all the files for the platform but i really have no idea where to host them or how to connect them to my wordpress website. 
More simply, i would like to know where to host this platform and how to link the login/register forms to my wordpress.

These are the files that i have for the platform.

Files:

[image: files]

Comment: You want to keep these two websites separate so you have a hope and prayer of maintaining it.  Integration between the two is going to be very specific to what you need to connect.  This isn't going to be a "install the integration plugin, done" solution.  You are going to need to create wordpress plugins, api's and other forms of middleware to connect the specific things you need.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on REST/Oauth2 or SOAP so you can communicate from WordPress with a custom plugin to your Cake application. As a rule of thumb NEVER put your secure files on the server where you host WordPress.

Comment: @JohanKoele Can you please elaborate? I would think in ~20 years Wordpress should have matured to be secure enough?